# Adding additional tags to flutter-markdown?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, markdown

Im trying to add support for additional tags in Flutter-markdown. I have just not been able to figure out how.

It seems that Flutter-markdown internally uses markdown. So I'm not sure where should I be doing this or both.

Basically I want to add an additional tag [[id,text]] . This should basically create a hyperlink in my Flutter widget to say abc.com/id/text